# Dynamically Filter datalist in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Being a newbie and exploring more with HTML5 tags i am stuck to figure out how to make dynamic data list for drop downs which will be used in registration pages. My requirement is to make two dropdowns (one for countries and other for states in that  country) On selection of particular country in one drop down it should only show states of that country in the next drop down.How can i achieve this, I explored on data list HTML5 tags but cannot achieve filtering (condition based scenario) with this.
 I ma looking for something like this(selection filtering in dropdowns)
    http://ticketdada.com/index.aspx

Comment: Sounds like a job for [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).
It is very good at dynamically changing displayed data.

Comment: i am not pointing with .net here. all i am interested is to get this into our website as easy as possible